# For iOS, is it possible to run git command?

Tags: ios, git

I want to run git command in my app, so I can git pull/commit/clone with the repo. Is it possible? How to do? I search for google for the topic , and cannot find the answer. Any idea, thanks a lot.!

Answer (score 2):

Git is not available on iOS like it is available on OS X. On OS X you can call any command line command using NSTask, but NSTask is not available on iOS.
The **only** way to achieve what you want to do is get the Git source code and include it in your app.

Remember that normally the user interfaces with the app by executing the program 'git' and giving as arguments for instance `clone <myRepo>`. This means that the program 'git' gets two args in the main function and from their does what needs to be done. The program git does not exist in you case, as that is now your app, and the arguments can still be the same, e.g. via textfields.

Answer (score 1):

Git is open source https://github.com/git/git and written in C. So in theory you could include it as library in your application.

There is a git client on AppStore so its definitely doable https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/working-copy-powerful-git/id896694807?mt=8

But I don't image that it will be super straight forward and would not recommend it unless you have a lot of time on your hands

Comment: thank you. Your word inspire me. I have a look at the source code. It is really a heavy work to do. Thanks for your suggestion.